# For C/C++, when people say code is insecure, does it mean the application will crash, or it can be abused to launch cyber attack?

Tags: c++, c, security, memory, secure-coding

I have seen in many instances when people say codes are "insecure".

- Accessing an array beyond bound is "insecure".
- Malloc without free is insecure.
- Dangling pointer is "insecure".
- No bound checking user input is "insecure".

In the above example, I understand in the fourth instances, under specific context, such as if you are writing your code to check the user input against a password database, your code can be abused to cause a buffer overflow and allow fraudulent user to authenticate. However I don't understand how your code can be abused in the other cases to endanger the user's computer.

Can I know when people say "insecure", is there any chance they really mean either your program can be abused for an attacker's gain, or your program can crash?

Comment: What you listed is not the complete list. It can use open channel for transferring private and sensitive data. It can collect private data... This question is off topic here.

Comment: The overarching theme is that secure code does what it is designed for, and insecure code can potentially do something unintended by the developer and unwanted by the end user.   So (1) accessing an array out of bounds is insecure anything can happen as a result (2) `malloc()` without `free()` is insecure because it can leak resources and (eventually) compromise behaviour of the program (or the system it runs on) (3) a dangling pointer is insecure anything can happen as a result (4) unchecked user input is insecure because invalid input (e.g. out of range) can cause unpredictable execution.

Comment: A program doesn't have to crash to be insecure.  Consider a software system operated by a bank to manage customer accounts.    If a customer can enter bad data to the system and then access data about accounts of other customers, then that system is insecure whether the system crashes or not.

Comment: @Peter
Thanks for your comment. I understand a program doesn't have to crash to make it insecure. I have changed the wording slightly. For example the buffer overflow bug will in many cases not crash your program.

However at least from a system security perspective, when you say something is "insecure" , it usually means it can be leveraged for the attacker's gain under some instances. Again, the buffer overflow is such an example - it allows an unauthenticated user to log in.

Comment: @Peter
I wonder how the other circumstances can be leveraged. For example, can a dangling pointer bug be abused to access memory space belonging to other programs, hence allowing the attacker to steal data or inject malicious code? That is the sort of answer I was looking for.

Comment: A program is insecure as soon as there is a potential for it to behave in unwanted ways.  On modern operating systems, a dangling pointer in a user program is unlikely to result in accessing the memory space in other processes - because the OS is designed to recognise and/or prevent such things.  But it is possible in specific circumstances, such as dereferencing that pointer causing an interaction with other insecure code that happens to be in the OS or a device driver. A modern OS is designed (and continually updated) to reduce chances of such things happening though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invocation of undefined behavior is always insecure. The first item (array access our of bounds) is automatically in that category. The fourth is just an example of the first, conditional on user interaction (those pesky users). I.e. the *potential* to overreach an input buffer has the *potential* to invoke *undefined behavior*, and therefore insecure.

That leaves the middle two.

Failing to free dynamic memory will *eventually* lead to operational failure, as the OS will (usually) terminate such a program, under *its* rules, not yours. When and how this happens isn't the concern; that it *can* happen *at all* is a *big* concern. This is an ingredient of "crappy code", but moreover has the *potential* for a security issue. Whatever conditions are required to repeat the leak need only be done with extreme prejudice until such time as the OS tears down the application, and with that you have a DoS (denial of service) accomplishment.

Dangling pointers are just UB laying in-wait. They are yet-more ingredients in crappy code. Just sitting there, they don't do anything. However, they present an *opportunity* for such a problem when they are dereferenced. Once that transpires it joins the first and fourth items in the basket of UB, and is therefore automatically "insecure". It can also become problematic when the value of the pointer itself is treated as a state unto its own, though that is highly situational and rarer than the simple dereference workflow.

The short answer is: *all* UB is automatically insecure. Two of the four items present instantly fit into that basket. A third potentially fits into that basket under the right usage conditions. The fourth (failing to free memory) is a flat-out bug that will eventually lead to process termination outside the purview of you, the code author, but is enhanced if exploitable to promote a DoS conclusion.

The super short answer: Don't write code that invokes UB, and don't write crappy code in-general.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I really cannot agree with calling harmless Undefined Behavior as "Insecure", this does answer my original question "what do people mean when they talk about insecure coding" and therefore I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` without `free`, and dangling pointers, result in memory leaks. If you leak too much memory, it will cause the program to use excessive memory. If it uses too much memory, it might crash, it could cause performance problems on the system because other applications can't get the memory they need, or it could even cause the system to run out of virtual memory.

These types of issues are mostly a concern for long-running applications like servers. Imagine a server that runs constantly, leaking a megabyte every hour. That's a gigabyte every 40 days.